# Matrices: Different dimensions + implementation

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to implement 2 matrices that I must use without having user input and multiplying it with each other. However, they have different dimensions. How would I be able to code the this? I literally tried everything that i deleted my code and restarting it.

```
main(void){
int B[4][3] = {{1,0,0}, {1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}};
int Y[1][4] = {{1}, {1}, {1}, {0}};
 }
```

Comment: So you tried this. It must not have worked or you wouldn't here. But doesn't-work is a symptom as much an outcome. Future readers for your question should be gifted with knowing what actually *happened* when you tried this. Error messages? Warnings ? Unrelated, kudos for scrapping what you did before and starting over down to this absolutely minimal code.

Comment: it's not possible to multiply 4x3 matrix with 4x1. The inner dimensions hav to match (e.g. 3x4 with 4x1)

Comment: Yeah I remembered that, It is a 1x4, i just confuse rows and columns at times.

Comment: Please do not edit questions with corrections made in the answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
int Y[1][4] = {{1}, {1}, {1}, {0}};
```

is not right. That would be good for a  `4 x 1` array.

```
int Y[4][1] = {{1}, {1}, {1}, {0}};
```

What you need is:

```
int Y[1][4] = {{1, 1, 1, 0}};
```

Now you can multiply.

```
int main ()
{
   int B[4][3] = {{1,0,0}, {1,0,1},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}};
   int Y[1][4] = {{1, 1, 1, 0}};
   int R[1][3] = {0};

   for ( int i = 0; i < 1; ++i )
   {
      for ( int j = 0; i < 3; ++j )
      {
         for ( int k = 0; i < 4; ++k )
         {
            R[i][j] += Y[i][k]*B[k][j]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah okay! I see now!

Comment: Wouldn't i have to Transpose matrix B in order for it to be a 3X4?
and then multiply transpose Y matrix so it can be 3X4 and a 4X1?